# How to use Van der Corput's lemma to get the following estimates?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, oscillatory-integral

Recently, I'am reading Tao's article ***Spherically Averaged Endpoint Strichartz Estimates for The Two-dimensional Schrodinger Equation***, and the link of the article is there

[Spherically Averaged Endpoint Strichartz Estimates for The Two-dimensional Schrodinger Equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9811168).

in which there are some problems that I can't solve by myself.

We define Bessel function by

\begin{equation}
J_n(\lambda)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{i\lambda \cos\theta} e^{in\theta} d\theta
\end{equation}

and decompose $J_n$ smoothly by 
\begin{equation}
J_n(\lambda)=m_0(\lambda)+m_1(\lambda)+\sum_{2^j \gg n} m_j(\lambda), 
\end{equation}

where $m_0,m_1,m_j$ are supported on $|r| \ll n , |r|\sim n$ and $|r| \sim 2^j \gg n$ respectively.

As for $m_1$ and its derivative, Tao says using Van der Corput's lemma, we can get the following estimates:

> - \begin{equation}|m_1(\lambda)|\lesssim n^{-1/3}(1+n^{-1/3}|\lambda-n|)^{-1/4},\end{equation}
> - \begin{equation}|m_1'(\lambda)| \lesssim n^{-1/2}. \end{equation}

Can someone present details of the argument to the two estimates above?

Comment: I think this is better suited to MathOverflow. Include a link to the arXiv of the paper you are reading.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327129/how-to-use-van-der-corputs-lemma-to-get-the-following-estimates

Comment: Do you know what Van der Corput's Lemma is, Tao?

Comment: @Tao.Zhou: I don't think you will get anywhere by applying that lemma as a black box. More than "van der Corput lemma", this is "stationary phase principle" that you should apply. Maybe search the net for "stationary phase Bessel function asymptotics" or something like that.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, oh, thank you very much. I think I should try to learn some more knowledge about oscillatory integral.

Comment: @Tao.Zhou: I have been saying the same thing for years... :-) If you find something, please let me know. I must confess that I spent some time today trying to understand this question, without success. I see that, when $\lambda < n$, the phase is never stationary, so we have strong decay when $n\to \infty$. When $\lambda =n$, the phase is stationary at some points, so the decay is slower. I understand that this is the philosophy, but I cannot do the precise computation.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: OK! I try it !